# mariadb.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: Permission denied / Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning

Tags: mariadb

I just installed MariaDB and the status is :

```
* mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.18 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-01-28 15:29:00 UTC; 2s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/

Jan 28 15:29:00 54 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.18 database server...
Jan 28 15:29:00 54 systemd[29206]: mariadb.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: Permission denied
Jan 28 15:29:00 54 systemd[29206]: mariadb.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/bin/install: Permission denied
Jan 28 15:29:00 54 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Jan 28 15:29:00 54 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 28 15:29:00 54 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.18 database server.
```

Can I have some help to start MariaDB
Thx

Answer (score 19):

This question is quite old – but since I found it through Google after running into the same issue, here’s my solution:

The problem started occurring after updating a MariaDB instance running inside an LXC container.

As a quick fix, I created `/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/lxc.conf` with the following contents:

```
[Service]
ProtectHome=false
ProtectSystem=false

# These settings turned out to not be necessary in my case, but YMMV
#PrivateTmp=false
#PrivateNetwork=false
#PrivateDevices=false
```

After that, run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart mariadb` and everything should work again.

Comment: I doubt this is the correct answer. The error clearly states that the problem happens  in the line `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld` . Indeed the proposed solution does not solve the problem.

Comment: @am70 The error also states 'Permission denied', indicating that some security feature is getting in the way. Which is what my configuration file is disabling. I ran into this issue several times and this solution always did the trick. I'm sorry it doesn't work for you, perhaps there's some other underlying cause.

Comment: This solved the issue for me after upgrading from stretch to buster, but I had to uncomment the line `#PrivateDevices=false`

Comment: I can confirm that after creating an LXC container on Proxmox and installing the latest MariaDB (10.5.9), I had the same issue with starting Mariadb on Debian 10. Creating the file and using the above settings/commands made it work. Thank you!

Comment: In a debian lxc container after removing the php version this error occurred. And this solution was successful. But in my case the commented out lines were important to success. So Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was my problem, just create the directory and paste this config fixed it !

Comment: Same issue continues to bother Debian 12 LXC on Proxmox. I needed to create the folder before creating the file by the way.

Answer (score 5):

I had to do both:

```
ProtectHome=false
ProtectSystem=false
```

and uncomment:

```
#PrivateDevices=false
```